# Inserting Updated data in a table to another table

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a table named "employees" that has an emp_id,firstname, lastname, age, salary,email, password, address and a telephone number.This table has records. I've got another table named requests that is empty and has the same info including a req_id. If i updated any data in the employees table i'd like the records to be inserted only in the requests table. That's what i did so far, but it doesn't seem to work.

*code:*

**editInfo.php**

```
<html>

<body>
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "project";

$conn =  new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

mysqli_select_db($conn, 'project');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees";
$records = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> LastName </th>
        <th> FirstName </th>
        <th> Age </th>
        <th> Salary </th>
        <th> Email </th>
        <th> Password </th>
        <th> Address </th>
        <th> Telephone </th>

    </tr>
    <?php


     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
     {
        echo "<tr><form action=update.php method=post>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=lname value='".$row['LastName']."'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=fname value='".$row['FirstName']."'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=age value='".$row['Age']."'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=salary value='".$row['salary']."'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=email value='".$row['email']."'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=password name=pass value='".$row['emp_password']."'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=address value='".$row['address']."'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=text name=telephone value='".$row['telephone']."'></td>";
        echo "<input type= hidden name=id value='".$row['Emp_ID']."'>";
        echo "<td><input type=submit>";
        echo "</form></tr>";

     }


    ?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**update.php**

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "project";

$conn =  new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

mysqli_select_db($conn, 'project');

//UPDATE QUERY

$sql = "UPDATE requests SET LastName='$_POST[lname]', FirstName='$_POST[fname]', Age='$_POST[age]', salary='$_POST[salary]', 
email='$_POST[email]', emp_password='$_POST[pass]', address='$_POST[address]', telephone ='$_POST[telephone]'
WHERE Emp_ID=$_POST[id]";


if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    header("refresh:1; url= editInfo.php");
else
    echo "not updated";


?>
```

Comment: incorrect attribute value type=text name=lname | correct this  type='text' name='lname'

Comment: type=submit also

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent sql inection

Comment: it will updated the records in the requests table if the same records already exists there and as per your statement it seems it does not exists there. So you need to use insert query instead of update query.

Comment: *but it doesn't seem to work.* is not an error description

Comment: there are no errors. it works just fine when i update the employee table instead of the requests table. However, when the user updates data i want the data to be transferred to the requests table. i don't want to change any records in the employee table @Jens

Comment: first you need to insert the data into the requests table then only you can update also as you mentioned Emp_ID is for employee table requests table has req_id

Comment: at the time of insert , insert the data in both tables and then update requests table

Comment: Thank you!! @AmitSharma

Comment: Welcome @Nour.upvote please

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create a file 'db.php' where you include you db connection for all page, second use statement for prepare query (prevent sql injection):

**edit info**

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM employees");

?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> LastName </th>
        <th> FirstName </th>
        <th> Age </th>
        <th> Salary </th>
        <th> Email </th>
        <th> Password </th>
        <th> Address </th>
        <th> Telephone </th>

    </tr>
    <?php


     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
     {
       //ALL ROWS
     }
```

**update.php**

```
<?php

require 'db.php';
$lastname = $_POST['lname'];
$firstname = $_POST['fname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$salary = $_POST['salary'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$emp_password = $_POST['pass'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$phone = $_POST['telephone'];
$empid = $_POST['id'];

//UPDATE QUERY

$sql = $conn->prepare("UPDATE requests SET LastName=?, FirstName=?, Age=?, salary=?, email=?, emp_password=?, address=?, telephone =?    WHERE Emp_ID=?");
$sql->bind_param('sssssssss', $lastname, $firstname, $age, $salary, $email, $emp_password, $address, $phone, $empid);

if ($sql->execute()) {
    header("refresh:1; url= editInfo.php");
} else {
    echo "not updated";
}
```